# Samba 4 not working as an AD-DC

Tags: active-directory, samba

I am trying to get Samba working as a AD-DC on a Debian machine but having little luck, I managed to get the Samba-ad-dc service up and running after disabling nmbd and smbd services but now when I try to let my Win 7 machine search for a domain it doesn't find any.

Also if I log onto the Debian machine and execute `smbclient -L localhost -U%` it gives `session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`.

Here is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        netbios name = SERVERNAME
        realm = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN.LAN
        workgroup = SERVERNAME
        dns forwarder = 192.168.168.1
        server role = active directory domain controller
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/servername.domain.lan/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No
```

My final goal is to use this server as AD-DC, file server and email server. So for now I want to know how to get windows clients to find the domain and register to it.

EDIT:

Here is my `/etc/krb5.conf`

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.LAN
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

Comment: (OT) read "AD-DC" as "AC/DC" )

Answer (score 2):

I've hit this today too :).

The issue is that you need to have the winbind package installed as well on the AD-DC for that smbclient command to work (and it's not a dependency of the samba package, so if you just installed samba it won't get pulled in). I don't think winbind is necessarily needed for an AD-DC (from my brief skim of some reading material), but the -L command against the AD-DC doesn't seem to work on that setup without the winbind package installed.

To get the above smbclient command working without the internal error on the AD-DC also do:

```
apt install winbind
service winbind stop
service winbind disable
service samba-ad-dc restart
```

Comment: this worked for me (even though winbind service itself would not start on my box)

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with "realm" of smb.conf. If

```
netbios name = SERVERNAME
```

then you should cut "SERVERNAME." from realm:

```
realm = DOMAIN.LAN
```

could you post the content of `/etc/krb5.conf`

And also try

```
kinit administrator
```

then

```
klist
```

What you could do also to troubleshoot is to launch the smbclient command with a higher debug level to try to locate the issue:
smbclient -d 3 -L localhost -U%

and check if there is any error messages in the log (if necessary, you can add "`log level = 3`" in global section of smb.conf to make it more verbose):

```
journalctl -u samba-ad-dc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added my krb5.conf file to the question. The `kinit`, isn't that a KDE application? I don't find it on my system and apt finds a KDE package called kinit, that is not what you meant right?

Comment: Ahh, found it in package `krb5-user`.

Comment: kinit is for Kerberos: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/user_commands/kinit.html     What i suggest you (if you can) is to go for a full reinstall and follow this procedure: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

Comment: The `kinit administrator` gives an error: `kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "DOMAIN.LAN" while getting initial credentials`. I changed the krb5.conf to match the smb.conf and put `default_realm = DOMAIN.LAN` instead of `SERVER.DOMAIN.LAN`.

Comment: And for install: "apt-get install samba krb5-user winbind smbclient dnsutils "when krb5-user asks for infos put: Default Kerberos Realm --> "DOMAIN.LAN" Kerberos server for realm --> server.domain.lan  Administrative server for realm --> server.domain.lan

Comment: If you search a more concise HowTo, this one is quite complete: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_9&p=samba&f=4